# Can't Add Strongly-Typed View With Model From Referenced Assembly in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a solution with an ASP.NET MVC 3 project, and a class library project.  I created a reference to the class library, "Commands", in the web project, which is resolving; copy-local is also set to true and Commands.dll is being copied into the web project's bin directory.

When I try to add a strongly-typed view, selecting a class from Commands as the model, I receive a "Could not load file or assembly" error for the Commands assembly.

I've tried removing and re-adding the reference, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, etc. but still have the problem.

Something else odd about this is that when I click "Add view" in the controller to get to the add view dialog, the model in the referenced assembly is available in the "Model class:" drop-down.

Comment: Have you checked the target framework versions of your project and the referenced assemblies for compatibly mismatches?

Comment: The target frameworks are both 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Fully qualified name for the model class in your view.

Ex : `@model YourClassLibraryNameSpace.YourClassname`

Comment: I'm able to manually create strongly-typed views, but can't use the wizard.